# Coldfusion 10 with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, apache2.4

I'm trying to install Coldfusion 10 with Apache 2.4 on Windows 2012 Server but I can't get it to work.

There has been a lot said about installing with Apache 2.4 but I have not found anywhere how it's done or that it's even possible.

Am I trying the impossible?

If not, can anybody help or direct me to a tutorial/documentation what needs to be done to get it working?

Now when I start Apache 2.4 I get this error in the Windows Application eventlog:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 523 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of C:/Apache24/conf/mod_jk.conf: Cannot load C:\\ColdFusion10\\config\\wsconfig\\1\\mod_jk.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Any help is very welcome! Even if the advise it to forget about 2.4 and switch back to 2.2

Many thanks!

Comment: This looks like a file path error - not a 2012 thing. Try changing that line to to: "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\mod_jk.so"  and make sure the file actually exists. It's a guess but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it working.

What I did:

To start of with, I used Apache 2.2 so I got CF working, I logged into the Admin then installed all updates.

After that, I used wsconfig (C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\bin) then I configured CF with Apache 2.4 and removed it for Apache 2.2.

And voila, Coldfusion running perfectly with Apache 2.4

I'm sure you can download the update files from Adobe so you don't need to first run with Apache 2.2 but for now this works for me.